# Full name and year as BibTeX key

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'd like to reference BibTeX sources with full name and year, e. g. [Adams1979]. Is there an easy way to to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the `natbib` or `biblatex` packages. Either should be able to do what you want.

Edit: Take a look at `\setcitestyle` for `natbib`.

Edit 2: Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setcitestyle{square,aysep={}}
\begin{document}
\citep{adams:79}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

And the `.bib`:

```
@Article{adams:79,
        author = {Foo Adams},
        year = 1979,
        title = {Test},
        journal = {Test},
}
```

Comment: Ah, good catch Joseph. That was there for something I tried that didn't work, intended to remove the space before the year. I forgot to delete it.

Comment: Am I right that there is no way to include the full or abbreviated first name of the author using natbib?

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use natbib to get the references with full name and year. You can do the same by using apalike bibliographystyle and you'll just type the following snippet in your tex file:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `natbib` you only need to specify something like

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

You can read its full documentation by typing `texdoc natbib` on a command line.